# how to get sums in CSV file python

Tags: python

[enter image description here][1][enter image description here][2]I have a CSV file with 14 categories with 303 lines I need to find the sum for each category. What I have so far sadly it isn't much any help on how to find the sum of each category singly and 
abbreviated 14 categories are in order as age,gen,cpt,rbp,sc,fbs,rer, mhra,eia,sd,spsd,nmv,dt,hd

```
    import string
with open("train.csv", "r") as f:
    for hd in f.read ():13
```

The first few lines are as this

A      B     C    D      E    f    G     H    I     J     K    L      M      N

63     1    1   145     233    1   2   150    0     2.3   3    0      6      0

67      1    4   160    286    0   2   108    1     1.5   2    3       3      2

67      1     4   120    229   0   2   129    1     2.6   2    2      7       1

Comment: I think you mean csv file, correct?

Comment: what does the file look like?

Comment: The file is A-N with 303 lines
there is a list of numbers for each category one per line

Comment: So all numbers after the header line? Or no header but the data is in the order in your question?

Comment: @Dandy, don't add an image, add the first few lines

Comment: It wont let me add a picture since im new. But its a list of numbers for each category its suppose to be used to determine if you have Heart disease depending on your info.

Comment: @Dandy, presuming you have comma separated values then the code in my answer will give you  the total sum for each column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *map* each row to *float*, *transpose* and *sum* each column making a dict with (column_name, column_sum) pairings:

```
import  csv

with open("train.csv", "r") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    # pull first row i.e A,B,C,D... to use ad the keys
    keys = next(r)
    # iterate ober the rows mapping to float and transpose
    # with zip(*... so rows become columns, one per key
    summed_dict = dict(zip(keys, map(sum, zip(*(map(float, row) for row in r)))))
```

For your input sample:

```
A,B,C,D,E,f,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N
63,1,1,145,233,1,2,150,0,2.3,3,0,6,0
67,1,4,160,286,0,2,108,1,1.5,2,3,3,2
67,1,4,120,229,0,2,129,1,2.6,2,2,7,1
```

Outputs:

```
{'K': 7.0, 'D': 425.0, 'B': 3.0, 'G': 6.0, 'f': 1.0, 'N': 3.0, 'M': 16.0, 'C': 9.0, 'A': 197.0, 'E': 748.0, 'L': 5.0, 'H': 387.0, 'I': 2.0, 'J': 6.4}
```

You could use a DictReader but there is no real advantage using it here.

Comment: ok sweet thank you this helps out though just to make sure how I get it the keys = next (r) is what makes the the code continue after starting on column A am I correct?

Comment: @Dandy, as you look at the file `next(r)` pull A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N, so they are the keys/columns, then each row in for row in r are the rest of the rows 63,1,145 etc.. zip(*...) transposes so basically we take the values vertically/column wise as opposed to row wise so each key matches up to the sum of the values below it

Answer (score 0):

Python has a really useful 'csv' module.

```
import csv

with open("train.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        # work on each row as a list
```

There is also the handy DictReader which parses the first line of the CSV as row headers and then gives you each row as a dictionary with keys set to the headers.

Now that the data is in an easy to consume format the summation should be easy.

Answer (score -1):

Numpy might be your friend:

```
import numpy as np

# load array from csv
arr = np.loadtxt('data.csv', dtype=float, delimiter=';', skiprows=0)

n = -1
# get n-th row by fany indexing
row = arr[n,:]
print row
print np.sum(row)

m = 2
# get m-th col by fancy indexing
col = arr[:,m]
print col
print np.sum(col)
```

it is pretty much self explanatory. for further information: [read the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)

Comment: im not sure what numpy does. I was told to be simplistic about it but I'll look it up it seems useful.

Comment: if you want to do numeric operations on the values stored in the csv file (which I assumed, because you asked for category/column sum), numpy is the way to go. It basically implements multi-dimensional, statically typed arrays. as a matter of fact it is partly implemented in C, thus it is quiet fast as well

Comment: @Dandy,  numpy is not part of the standard library, you would need to install it   if you have large arrays of data numpy is very efficient but for a 300~ line file pure python well be more than sufficient,

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham, it is perfectly fine to use NumPy for small datasets as well. Combined with MathPlotLib (=SciPy), it is a somewhat a feature-complete alternative to MatLab while keeping a pythonic interface. Btw: most distributions come with NumPy already included. Chances are, he already got it installed.